# undefined method `wikis_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having issues getting my create method to function correctly.

Here is my new.html.erb file

```
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_for @wiki do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :title, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter wiki title" %><br><br>

      <%= f.label :body, class: 'form-control'%>
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter wiki body" %><br><br>

      <%= f.check_box :private %> Private Topic<br><br>

      <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Controller

```
  def new
    @wiki = Wiki.new
  end
  def create
    @wiki = Wiki.create(params[:wiki])
    if @wiki.save
      flash[:notice] = "Wiki has been saved"
      redirect_to wiki_index_path
    end
  end
private
  def wiki_params
    params.require(:wiki).permit(:title, :body, :private)
  end
```

`routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :wiki
  post 'wiki/new'
  post 'wiki/create'
  resources :users
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

If I use :wiki in my form_for on new.html.erb I can get passed the error but when clicking on my save button on the actual new page, nothing happens at all (since I'm not saving the information to the correct variable). However, as soon as I use the @wiki variable, I get the error

```
"undefined method `wikis_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8f794e5d58>:0x007f8f7bb2ef50>"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: `get wiki/new` not `post wiki/new`

Comment: updated routes, but still getting the same error

Comment: I believe you want `@wiki = Wiki.new(params[:wiki])` instead of `@wiki = Wiki.create(params[:wiki])` in your `create` action

Comment: updated my create method to `@wiki = Wiki.new(params[:wiki])` but it made no difference

Comment: @Rapid99 No it's not about the main problem. Just another one tiny tweak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of redundant unrestful wiki routes. `resources :wikis` will be enough:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :wikis
  resources :users
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

And something tells me that all will be fine after that change.

Comment: I removed the other routes and restarted my server. I am still getting the following error when trying to access /wiki/new

undefined method `wikis_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa5e541d628>:0x007fa5e4e30c60>

Comment: @Rapid99 Did you change `resources :wiki` to `resources :wikis`?

Comment: I did now, but it seems to have broken a lot. I am trying to clean it all up now and see if it makes a difference

Comment: you were correct. I made a rookie mistake of naming my controller "wiki_controller.rb" instead of "wikis_controller.rb". This messed up a lot. But after correcting my routes and refactoring my error files, everything is working as it should!

Comment: Glad to help you! I'll appreciate if you accept my answer as correct one.