# Rails - NoMethodError in Home#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have converted a front end project to the Rails environment, and I have used Material Design Lite to design the form fields. I am getting the following error:

NoMethodError in Home#new - 
undefined method `homes_path'

Can anyone help me fix the error?

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get '/home', to: 'home#index'
  get '/home/new', to: 'home#new'
  get 'home/:id', to: 'home#show'
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<div class="container-div">
  <!-- Colored FAB button with ripple -->
  <button id="fab" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </button>

  <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <div class="mdl-card__title" id="text-div">
      <h2 id="title-text" class="mdl-card__title-text">CAMPAIGN</h2>
      <br>
      <br>
      <span id="success">Success!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">

      <%= form_for(@home) do |f| %>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <%= f.text_field_tag :campaign_name,nil,:class => "mdl-textfield__input"%>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="campaign_name">Campaign Name</label>
          </div>

          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <%= f.text_field_tag :phone_number_receiver,nil,:class => "mdl-textfield__input",:type => "number" %>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="phone_number_receiver">Phone Number for recipient</label>
            <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a number!</span>
          </div>

          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <%= f.text_field_tag :start_date,nil,:class => "mdl-textfield__input"%>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="start_date" id="start-date-label">Enter start date</label>
          </div>


          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <%= f.text_field_tag :end_date,nil,:class => "mdl-textfield__input"%>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="end_date" id="end-date-label">Enter end date</label>
          </div>

          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <%= f.text_field_tag :start_time,nil,:class => "mdl-textfield__input"%>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="start_time" id="start-time-label">Enter time</label>
          </div>

          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield less-margin mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <%= f.text_area_tag :sms_msg, nil,:class => "mdl-textfield__input", :rows => 8, :cols => 40 %>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sms_msg">Text Message</label>

          </div>

          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
            <%= text_field_tag :break_msg,"1",:class => "mdl-textfield__input"%>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="break_msg">Number of Pages</label>
          </div>
      <%end%>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

home_controller.rb:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @campaigns = Home.all
  end

  def new
    @home = Home.new
  end

  def show
    @campaign = Home.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

PS: The form field for :break_msg is not a part of the model Home.

Link to github: https://github.com/rimildeyjsr/sms-scheduler

Comment: AFAICT there isn't a `homes_path`, just a `home_path`, no? Just run `rake routes`.

Comment: No, there is no homes_path. I ran the command, there is not such path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your form is pointing to a route (`homes_path` or `/homes`) that doesn't exist. You need to create a `POST` route and corresponding controller action.

```
post '/home', to: 'home#create', as: :homes
```

Keep in mind, the `as: :homes` may be optional. Run `rake routes` to verify.

And for the controller action, something like this:

```
def create
  @home = Home.create(home_params)
  ...
end
```

For more info, check out the [Rails docs on controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html).

**EDIT:** Also, you're using `text_field_tag` and `text_area_tag` in your form but since you're using an ActiveRecord object (`@home`) then you don't need the `_tag`. So, just `f.text_field` and `f.text_area`.

Lastly, you should use the `resources` helper instead of manually creating the "home" routes. Read through the [Rails docs on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info and customization options (e.g. getting `/home` instead of `/homes` when using `resources :homes`).

Comment: I added the code you asked me to, without the as: :homes . I am getting the same error again

Comment: Did you add the `create` action? Also, try it with `as: :homes`.

Comment: Yes, I have added the create action. Trying it with as: : homes gives this error - undefined method `text_field_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x83b43a0>

Comment: The errors have gone, but a lot of my code is breaking. Specifically the functions I have defined in app/assets/javascripts/app.js

Comment: I assume you have logic that depends on the naming of the various input fields. If you'd like to keep using `text_field_tag` and `text_area_tag`, you should use `form_tag('/home')` instead of `form_for(@home)`. Then, remove all `f.` from the form code in the view. Check out the [Rails docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

this issue seems similar to an issue I had previously: [undefined method `wikis_path'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726686/undefined-method-wikis-path)

try renaming your controller to `homes_controller.rb`. This will create a bunch of errors that you will need to clean up (such as actually changing `class HomeController < ApplicationController` to `class HomesController < ApplicationController` as well as fixing your routes). This should address the issue of not having the `homes_path` route.